# How would you implement a navigation like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

How would you implement a navigation like this?

[image]

I'm a bit stuck and wondered if anybody could point me toward a good way to accomplish this.

Here's a transparent PNG of one of the hover states.

[image]

Comment: Since no one else has commented: please take a look at the close reason, and the FAQ it links too.  Questions on this site are really expected to show a bit of effort on your part.  You should show the code you have so far, whatever you attempted, and then ask specific questions about the challenges you're facing with implementing the design.  Good luck to you!

Answer (score 5):

your basic link group is a `<ul>`

```
<ul id="links">
    <li class="current"> <!--apply class "current" for current link-->
        <a>link1</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a>link2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

a little modification for `<a>` tags for better UX

```
#links a {
   display:block;     /*to make `<a>` not inline*/
   padding:           /*make the link hover/click area bigger*/
   text-align: right; /*the right-aligned text*/
}
```

now for the css, apply your "square indicator" to `<a>` <s>background to the "current" `<li>`. you could also do it</s> (for older browsers, hover does not apply on non-`<a>` elements)

```
li.current a{
    background-image:url(url_to_square_indicator);
    background-position: middle right; 
    /*
      you can use position to refine it's position.
      im not so sure about this if this "middle right" 
      is still applicable these days
    */
}
```

if you hover on the current link, swap out your image for the glowing one using `:hover`. you don't need to redeclare the styles applied from the previous, they just carry over. you are just swapping out the image. (in this case, background-position still applies)

```
li.current a:hover{
    background-image:url(url_to_glowing_indicator);
}
```

Comment: and don't forget to nest the link text in an additional `<a>` tag with the right `href` attribute pointing to the subpage.

Answer (score 0):

if I had to guess, I'd say an :hover changes the background, since it is an image file. Also make sure to set the background position and the repeat so that it only appears there.